# How can I change directory in C without resolving symlinks?

Tags: c, shell, symlink, cd, chdir

I'm trying to create a C program that emulates a Bash shell.

For the `cd file` instruction I use `chdir("file")` but it isn't correct because `chdir()` always resolves symlinks while `cd` doesn't by default.

I'm looking for a way to get a function that changes the current working directory without resolving symlinks.

Comment: Why do you think `cd` does not resolve symlinks?

Comment: Because I've tested it.

Comment: Perhaps you are using "resolve" with an different definition? bash `cd` always resolves symlinks, but it may pre- or post-process instances of `..` in the provided path (`cd -L`, `cd -P`) and it may search elsewhere for relative paths (`CDPATH`). If it didn't resolve the symlinks, it woudn't be able to change directory. Consider: `ln -s /nonexistent x; cd x`

Comment: Sorry if I'm misunderstood. When I do `ln -s dir dir2` then `cd dir2` then `pwd` the path is `xxx/dir2`. It cannot be achieved with `chdir()`. This is what I mean.

Comment: `$PWD` is a variable that bash manages. It doesn't have to match `realpath .`:  `mkdir -p a/b/c b c; ln -s a/b/c x; p()(echo "# cd $*";cd "$@"; echo "PWD=$PWD"; echo "realpath=$(realpath .)"); q()(p "$@";p -L "$@"; p -P "$@"); q x; q x/../c`

Comment: I know, but I want to emulate a bash shell. $PWD might be useful to get the initial non-resolved path, but then I have to use chdir() to change the current working directory

Comment: You have to _yourself_ store the path, as Bash does. In Bash program `chdir()` also returns the resolved path.

Comment: The thing is the `cd` instruction in bash does not resolves symlinks, whereas the `chdir()` function in C resolves them. I want to find a way NOT to resolve symlinks in C.

Comment: Maybe I am not using the word "resolve" right. If have a symlink `france2 -> world/europe/france` i want `cd france2/../` to give me my current path. Is that clear?

Comment: For better or worse, there is `cd -P /some/path` (physical) and `cd -L /some/path` (logical) and you can control whether Bash uses physical or logical mappings (Bash manual for [`cd`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-cd)).  By default, the mode is 'logical'; you can set 'physical' mode with [`set -P`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-set) or `set -o physical`.  You unset that with `set +P` or `set +o physical`.  The shell does a lot of tinkering to fool you about where the current directory is.

Comment: I know it, I'm trying to emulate a Bash shell. I use readlink() to read some instruction (in this case, cd some/path and I want my program to emulate what cd would do, ie change the current working directory without resolving symlinks. How to do that?